# Image and text intersection

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to do something like this:

[image]

As you can see, `Login` label should intersect with logo image. I tried such layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    style="@style/fullWidth"
    android:background="@drawable/login_logo" />

<LinearLayout
    style="@style/fullWidth"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout style="@style/labeledFieldLayout">
        <TextView style="@style/labeledFieldLabel"
                  android:text="@string/common_email"/>
        <EditText style="@style/labeledField_EditEmail"
                  android:id="@+id/emailEditor" />
    </LinearLayout>

........
</LinearLayout>
```

But of course, layouts are not intersect each other. Is it possible to solve? Maybe there is a way to set negative intervals..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, In your Layout your are Using Linear Layout as base , then it is possible to set negative intervals like as follow,

```
<LinearLayout
style="@style/fullWidth"
android:background="@drawable/login_logo" />
```

```
<LinearLayout style="@style/labeledFieldLayout"  android:layout_marginTop="-30dp">
    <TextView style="@style/labeledFieldLabel"
              android:text="@string/common_email"/>
    <EditText style="@style/labeledField_EditEmail"
              android:id="@+id/emailEditor" />
</LinearLayout>
```

........

Comment: Great! This works, but one more problem. The second layout overlaps the first (logo) and covers the image with it's background. Is there a way to make logo layout be `at the top`?

Answer (score 0):

Just have like this

```
<LinearLayout
style="@style/fullWidth" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/login_logo" /></LinearLayout>
```

```
<LinearLayout style="@style/labeledFieldLayout" >

    <TextView
        style="@style/labeledFieldLabel"
        android:text="@string/common_email" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailEditor"
        style="@style/labeledField_EditEmail" />
</LinearLayout>
```